# Disable scrolling upwards in UITextView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I am using a UITextView in a project, and I need it to only be able to scroll downwards (not upwards). Is there a way I can do this relatively easily? If not I may subclass UIScrollView or something weird, but I don't really want to do that.

Here is my basic UIViewRepresentable struct

```
struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    typealias UIViewType = UITextView
    var configuration = { (view: UIViewType) in }
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> UIViewType {
        let view = UIViewType()
        view.isEditable = false
        
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) {
        configuration(uiView)
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with simple subclass of `UITextView` to handle pan gesture activation.

Tested with Xcode 12

[image: demo]

```
class BottomScrollTextView: UITextView {
    override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        guard let gr = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer else { return true }

        return gr.translation(in: self).y < 0    // << allow only to down
    }

    private var _contentOffset = CGPoint.zero
    override var contentOffset: CGPoint {
        get { super.contentOffset }
        set {
            if newValue.y > super.contentOffset.y || self.isDecelerating {
                super.contentOffset = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {

    typealias UIViewType = UITextView
    var configuration = { (view: UIViewType) in }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> UIViewType {
        let view = BottomScrollTextView()   // << here !!

        // ... other code
```

Comment: I originally marked this as a solution, however, I found a flaw. If you begin to scroll downwards, and then scroll upwards in the same motion the view allows you to view the content above.

Answer (score 0):

UITextView is an extension of UIScrollView, so you can customize the scrollability directly in your makeUIView function:

```
func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> UIViewType {
    let view = UIViewType()
    view.isEditable = false
    view.bounces = false
    
    return view
}
```

That will stop the viewer from being able to scroll past the bounds of the view upwards.  If you wanted to stop them from being able to scroll back up after scrolling down, I think the best way would be disabling scrolling entirely (`view.isScrollEnabled = false`) and then adding a custom drag gesture to the object that only edits the view if it’s it’s downward.  [This tutorial](https://medium.com/better-programming/swiftui-drag-gesture-2559cf255c5e) might be a useful resource if that’s the case.